# Many to many relations Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using many to many relations in my symfony2 project, i have successfully made two entities 'Users' and `Groups` and i have also successfully persisted data which inserts data into `users`,`groups` and `users_groups` table by using

```
$user = new User();
$user->getGroups()->add($group);
```

now i want to edit the user which should also edit users_groups record..

I have searched a lot but no luck.Any help would be appreciated ...

CONTROLLER

```
   public function editAction()
  {
  if($this->getRequest()->query->get("id")){
        $id = $this->getRequest()->query->get("id");
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('DesignAppBundle:Users')->find($id);


        $editForm = $this->createForm(new UserType());


        if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $editForm->bindRequest($request);
        if ($editForm->isValid()) {

                           $postData = $request->request->get('users'); 


                            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                            ->getRepository('Bundle:groups');
                            $group = $repository->findOneById($postData['group']);

                            $entity->addGroups($group );

                            $em->flush();

                            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));            
            }

        }

        return $this->render('User.html.twig',array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        ));
    }       
  }
```

FORM

```
<?php

use and include .....


class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

         $builder->add('group', 'entity', array(
         'class' => 'Bundle:Groups',
         'property' => 'name',
         'empty_value' => 'All',
         'required' => true,
             'multiple'=>true,
         'data' => $request->get('group_id')
        ));



    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {

        return array(
            'validation_groups' => array('users'),
            'csrf_protection' => false,

        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

}
```

User

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Groups", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_groups",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/  
    protected $group;

 public function __construct()
{
    $this->group= new ArrayCollection();        

}

  public function addgroups(\Design\AppBundle\Entity\Categories $group)
    {
        $this->group[] = $group;
    }
```

Group

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Users", mappedBy="group")
     */
    protected $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users= new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add users
     *
     * @param Bundle\Entity\Users $users
     */
    public function addUsers(Bundle\Users $users)
    {
        $this->users[] = $users;
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
```

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: thanks for the link but at the moment something related to my question will be appreciated ....

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: OK, the code above shows how you persist the user and the group. Not really important, but you should have an `addGroup()` function in your user entity and call `$user->addGroup($group)`, instead of `$user->getGroups()->add($group);`. Now, you say that you want to edit the user and its group. What have you tried for that? Have you defined a form?

Comment: yeah i have the form but for simplicity i have hard coded the ids as `1`

Comment: i have the `addGroup()` in my entity but the problem is when i persist the data first it inserts the data into link table but i want to edit that entry using an edit form

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the form?

Comment: @Carlos Granados every thing is running fine, i only want a way to update data in link table i-e `user_group` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be adding the group_id, you should be adding the groups property

```
     $builder->add('groups');
```

The group_id column is automatically handled by Doctrine and you should not be handling it yourself directly. Do you have a group_id property? If you do, you should remove it.

The group entity should be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Users", mappedBy="group")
 */
protected $users;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->users= new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add users
 *
 * @param Bundle\Entity\User $user
 */
public function addUsers(Bundle\User $users)
{
    $this->users[] = $users;
}

/**
 * Get users
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}
```

**EDIT**

This is how your controller should be:

```
public function editAction($request)
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->query->get("id");

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('DesignAppBundle:Users')->find($id);

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new UserType(),$entity);

    if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $editForm->bindRequest($request);
        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
             $em->persits($entity);

             $em->flush();

             return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('index'));            
        }

    }

    return $this->render('User.html.twig',array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

and this is how your UserType should be:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {

         $builder->add('group', 'entity', array(
         'class' => 'Bundle:Groups',
         'property' => 'name',
         'empty_value' => 'All',
         'required' => true,
          'multiple'=>true,
        ));

    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {

        return array(
            'validation_groups' => array('users'),
            'csrf_protection' => false,

        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

}
```

Comment: same problem....its inserting a new entry in user_group table instead of updating the previous one

Comment: Can you post your User and Group entities? Only the bits relating to the relationship

Comment: I have exactly the same entity as posted by you ..... but i post annotations part only

Comment: The one you posted in your answer is not like mine! I can´t try to see your problem if you post the wrong data. Let´s do something: Go to pastebin.com and paste your exact User and Group entities, the controller , the form type and the form template in full. Just copy and paste the whole files

Comment: Sorry @Carlos Granados for confusing you,please check the updated code

Comment: Please do as I said and use pastebin.com. I cannot help you from incomplete information

Comment: sir i cant paste all the code because of company policies thats y i have to write the code here .... please compensate

Comment: Then edit your answer and post all your code bits in your CURRENT state. Also please include the code for the controller action which sets up the form and receives the form results

Comment: Please check my code now its in the current state ... the code below `EDIT` heading is of controller

Comment: Can you post the whole code for the controller action. It is important to find what is wrong

Comment: why have you changed `$entity = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Users')->find($id);` to `$entity = new Users();` ??? because this is the editUsers action and i am using your posted code for addUsers action ....

Comment: and where are u adding attributes to `$entity` ??

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this is user edit action no create new user action. Changed my code.

Comment: atttribute , $entity->addGroups($group)?? as in myController

Comment: Another problem is when i pass $entity to `$this->createForm(new UserType());` it says `Expected argument of type "object", "integer" given ` ...

Comment: regarding attributes, there is no need to add them manually. This is automatically done by the form bindRequest() call

Comment: Its not specifying error line but its 500 Internal Server Error-Unexpected type Exception - `Expected argument of type "object", "integer" given ` when i simply use `$this->createForm(new UserType()` it works ... but thats not my problem my problem is when i persist `$entity->addGroups($group)` it creates a new entry in user_group istead of updating it as its a edit form

Comment: Look There are two action one is AddUser Action and other is Edit UserAction the problem is in EditUser.Now There are three table Users Groups and uer_groups,when i add users useing AddUeser Action a record is entered in Users table and users_groups like `id=1, user_id=1 and group_id=1` now i want to edit User so that i can change group_id in user_groups table,how will i do it ??

Comment: group id will be coming from form, as usually done in edit form...For simplicity I want to change the groupId from 1 to 6 of User=>1. in my form groups are listing ...

Comment: It create a new entry as it does using AddUser Action, the rest of data is edited correctly in user table except in users_groups table...

Comment: You have to use $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity), otherwise your form is not associated to the entity and it creates a new one when binding the data. But I don´t know why you get the "Expected argument..." error. We need to know where this error is created. Run the code in the dev environment (use app_dev.php"), you will get a report saying where the problem happens